# Closed form of sum

Tags: analysis, summation

How to summarize

\begin{equation*}
f(x,y)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{(2n+1)\pi y}{d}\right)}{2n+1}\sin\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{d}?
\end{equation*}

I tried to calculate $\partial_y f$ and use geometric series, but it doesn't give me results.

The answer should be $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{\sin\frac{\pi x}{d}}{\sinh\frac{\pi y}{d}}$, but I have no idea how to obtain it.

Comment: Have you tried expanding the sine using $\sin t=\frac{\exp(it)-\exp(-it)}{2i}$ and distributing into two power series in $\exp(\frac{\pi(-y\pm ix)}d)$?

Comment: Yes, then $\partial_y f=\frac{i\pi}{d}\frac{\exp\left[\frac{4\pi i x}{d}\right]-1}{1+\exp\left[\frac{4\pi x i }{d}\right] -\exp\left[\frac{2\pi i x}{d}\right]\left(\exp\left[\frac{2\pi y}{d}\right]-\exp\left[-\frac{2\pi y}{d}\right]\right)}$

Comment: x @mikis: Huh? The plan I was sketching does not involve any $\partial_y$ at all.

Comment: Ok, but we need to eliminate factor $\frac{1}{2n+1}$ from this sum (if we want use known series), so the easiest way is to calculate $\partial_y$.

Comment: x @mikis: It's strange that you can declare something that _doesn't work for you_ to be the "the easiest way". Are you sure you're not confusing the situation with an example in your textbook where $y$ was actually the variable in the power series, such as $\sum_n \frac{y^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$? Just because there's a variable _called_ $y$ in this problem doesn't mean you should treat it like the variable called $y$ in another problem.

Comment: (Note also that the known series for arctangent already has a $2n+1$ in the denominator).

Comment: This series is from Laplace's equation in electrodynamics. I don't have any hints, any 'standard methods' etc. I only know what should be the answer (It is 'physically' well-know), so I tried to use any method - in this case I tried to use geometric series.  Ok, you have right - it can be calculate directly without differentiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Consider this sum as the imaginary part :
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\biggl(\exp\Bigl(-\frac{\pi(y+\mathrm i\mkern1mux)}d\Bigr)\biggr)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
It has the form $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{q^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$, which is the development of $$\operatorname{artanh} q=\frac12\ln(1+q)-\frac12\ln(1-q)$$
(This is the *complex* logarithm).

It will remain to express the imaginary part of the result.